# How to run artisan command as root (sudo user) in Laravel controller live server

Tags: laravel, sudo, laravel-artisan, database-backups

I use `Spatie/laravel-backup` package to backup my database. everything is ok in my local machine but in Live server when I run `sudo php artisan backup:run` in the terminal backup is taken successfully.

Inside `Laravel` controller when I run `Artisan::call('backup:run');` backup is not successful because the command create a backup directory inside `storage` it requires to run as `sudo`.

How can I run `Artisan::call('');` as `sudo`

Or any other ways to overcome this problem please.

there is my controller

```
    public function backup(Request $request)
    {
        try{
           Artisan::call('backup:run');

           return response()->json("Database backup was successful.");
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return response()->json($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I couldn't find any guid to run `Artisan::call('')` as sudo user.

Comment: is your server support **SUDO** command? if yes, then run the below command.
`Artisan::call('sudo backup:run')`

Comment: Yes my server support sudo, I get `"The command \"sudo\" does not exist."` error

Comment: Have you given the storage and bootstrap folder permission 0775? or second option used to make a cronjob like `crontab -e` and then add this line in it. check below reference site : https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-cron-job-task-scheduling-tutorialexample.html

Comment: I'm using `crontab` for daily backup but boss asking me to have a manual backup too.

Comment: Instead of running sudo in laravel, which gets complicated as you can see, why not whitelist certain commands the used can run without sudo as explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/1002870/whitelisting-commands-a-user-can-use-with-sudo

Comment: Instead of running the use command with sudo, give proper permissions to storage/{your_backup_folder} to write files with the user of the application, such as Apache.